# Differentiability with homogenous function (multivariable analysis)

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Could you please check my answers because I have a feeling I made mistakes especially in part c.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be homogenous of degree $\alpha>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

a) Show that $f$ is differentiable in 0 for $\alpha>1$ with derivative equal to 0.
A function $f$ is defferentiable if the following limit exists and equal to 0:
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - ah}{h} = 0
$$
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(h) - 0 - 0}{h} = 0
$$
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(h)}{h}
$$

$f$ is homogenous of degree $\alpha$ so $f(\lambda h) = \lambda^{\alpha}f(h)$ and thus
$$
\frac{f(h)}{h} = \frac{f(\lambda h)}{\lambda h} = \frac{\lambda^{\alpha}f(h)}{\lambda h} = \lambda^{\alpha-1} \frac{f(h)}{h}
$$
A theorem says that the limit of a homogenous function exists and is equal to $0$ if the function is homogenous of degree $\alpha > 0$. So when $\alpha > 1$, $\alpha - 1 > 0$. And thus the limit exists and is equal to 0.

b) Show that for $0<\alpha<1$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash\{0\}$ the directional derivative $D_{u} f(0)$ does not exist. Conclude then that $f$ is not differentiable.
$$
D_{u}f(0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(0+tu) - f(0)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(tu)}{t} 
$$
$$
= \frac{t^{\alpha}f(u)}{t} = t^{\alpha-1} f(u)
$$
So if it is now the case that $0 < \alpha < 1$ then $\alpha - 1 < 0$, so the limit of the function does not exist and thus the directional derivatives does not exist and thus $f$ is not differentiable.

c) In the case of $\alpha=1$, prove that the directional derivative $D_{u} f(0)$ exists if and only if $f(-u)=f(u)$. Conclude that $f$ is only differentiable if $f$ is linear.
$$
D_{u}f(0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(tu)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{t^{\alpha}f(u)}{t} =  \lim_{t\rightarrow0} t^{\alpha-1} f(u)
$$
$\alpha = 1$ so we get
$$
 \lim_{t\rightarrow0} t^{0} f(u) = f(u)
$$
So it has to be the case that $f(u) = f(-u)$
for $\leftarrow$ it is analogue.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your homegeneous means what I would call positively homogeneous.
That would be $f(\lambda h) = \lambda^{\alpha}f(h)$ for positive $\lambda$
(or nonnegative, perhaps.)

Take care what you do with $f(tu)$ in your calculations, respect the sign of $t$.

BTW, I do not know meaning of your symbol $\leftarrow$. For one-sided limits, we write $\lim_{t ???}$, where the question marks are either $~~\to0+~~$, $~~\to0-~~$ or $~~\searrow0~~$, $~~\nearrow0~~$, or rarely $\uparrow0$, $~~\downarrow0$.